# Saving website as document in SharePoint 2013

Tags: c#, pdf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I generate a page (html) dynamically inside an application page.

Now I need to archive that page inside the document library. PDF would be great, Word would be Ok. Html would be worst case.

If needed I could change the html to aspx of course.

While I found a lot of pages explaining SP2013s new PDF-Features for end users I did not find any example how to do this by code without using third-party tools.

Answer (score 2):

You can use new [SyncConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.word.server.conversions.syncconverter%28v=office.15%29.aspx) class introduced in SharePoint 2013 as part of Word Automation Services. To be able to use it you need to include `Microsoft.Office.Word.Server.dll` which is located in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI` folder.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Word.Server.Conversions;

var fileContent = "<html><body><h1> Blah Blah Blah </h1></body></html>";
using (var read = GenerateStreamFromString(fileContent))
using (var write = new MemoryStream())
using (var site = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
{
    var wordAutomationServiceName = "Word Automation Services";
    var sc = new SyncConverter(wordAutomationServiceName);
    sc.UserToken = site.UserToken;
    sc.Settings.UpdateFields = true;
    sc.Settings.OutputFormat = SaveFormat.PDF;

    var info = sc.Convert(read, write);
    if (info.Succeeded)
    {
        var folder = web.Lists["Documents"].RootFolder;
        folder.Files.Add("http://localhost/Documents/SyncConverted.pdf", write);
    }
}

public static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(s);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks! (Will accept that as answer after successfully tested)